# OnConfigurationChanged followed by OnStop ()?

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-lifecycle

I am stuck in a strange situation....
I have declared `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` in the manifest file of the Activity. So, ideally I want my Activity `onConfigurationChanged()` to be called whenever, I rotate the device. But, that does not happen.
Inspite of having these attributes in the manifest file, the Activity onStop() is called first followed by onCreate, (the `onConfigurationChanged()` is never called) when I rotate the device ----- This is the issue I am facing.

My expectation is --- Whenever, I rotate the device, onConfigurationChanged () to be called first, then onStop() and then onCreate().

1. What is the mistake that I am doing?
2. Is this at all possible ?

Comment: What is `minSdkVersion` you're targeting? And what's the API you're testing against?

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="14" , Testing against Android M (in a Nexus 9)

Comment: You don´t need to add `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` for `onConfigurationChanged()` to get called. 

The `onConfigurationChanged` method is called when you physically rotate an Android device. So, you need to rotate your device to see the method getting called. If you are indeed rotating the device and the method isn´t getting called maybe you should provide more context or code just to check and see what isn´t working as expected. I mean the activity and manifest...

Comment: Use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`.

Comment: I tried to log the onConfigurationChanged() method. It does not fire if manifest has android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" , but if I add screensize in configChanges, then only onConfigurationChanged() is fired.

Comment: @Onik :: sorry , but I can't use it, as I want my Activity to recreate with the additional onConfigurationChanged() to be also fired, which is not happening now.

Comment: _"then only onConfigurationChanged() is fired"_ what's unusual about that?

Comment: @Onik :: means if I add screensize --- > onConfigurationChanged() is fired.
If I add only android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden", it is not fired.
However, I can not have screensize. Do you have any suggesiton?

Comment: It's clearly stated [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) under the Caution section.

Comment: Caution area says --> "if you want to handle the activity recreation on orientation change, you need to declare screensize" . This does not meet my requirement. Plz see my question in the my expectation part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125246/discussion-between-onik-and-akash89).

Comment: Caution section says: "Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation" value." This explains why your expectation aren't met. The behavior correlates with the documentation and is a matter of min and target API.

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible.

You put `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`in your manifest to handle configuration changes yourself.

You override the `onConfigurationChanged()` method and take care of configuration changes there.

`onStop()` and `onCreate()` are *never* called again, only `onConfigurationChanged()` is called during a configuration change in this case because the activity is never killed.

Comment: :: so what I understand is, I need to mention screensize explicitly only then the onConfigurartionChanged() to be called? If I do not, declare screensize , every time the onStop will b called followed by onCreate() and onConfigurartionChanged() will not be called in that case. Is my understanding Correct?